# react-native how to assign assign multiple .replace() as a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `.replace()` method to filter my data.

Like this :

```
this.state.date.toString().slice(13,15)
.replace('Jan', '01')
.replace('Feb', '02')
.replace('Mar', '03')
.replace('Apr', '04')
.replace('May', '05')
.replace('Jun', '06')
.replace('Jul', '07')
.replace('Aug', '08')
.replace('Sep', '09')
.replace('Oct', '10')
.replace('Nov', '11')
.replace('Dec', '12')
.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

The problem is that I need to apply this method in multiple places and I want to assign all the `.replace()` method as a variable.

**edited**

I want to assign .replace() as a variable like this

```
const filter = .replace('Jan', '01')
.replace('Feb', '02')
.replace('Mar', '03')
.replace('Apr', '04')
.replace('May', '05')
.replace('Jun', '06')
.replace('Jul', '07')
.replace('Aug', '08')
.replace('Sep', '09')
.replace('Oct', '10')
.replace('Nov', '11')
.replace('Dec', '12')
.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

So I could use it like this :

```
this.state.date.toString().slice(13,15).filter
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the reply. You could ignore the .slice() method

Comment: If you are working on a Date object you can just get month number like `this.state.date.getMonth() + 1`

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to assign all the .replace() method as a variable*? Do you mean you need a function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry if i wasn't clear I edited my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to extract the logic into a function:

```
const changeToMonthNums = str => str
.replace('Jan', '01')
.replace('Feb', '02')
.replace('Mar', '03')
.replace('Apr', '04')
.replace('May', '05')
.replace('Jun', '06')
.replace('Jul', '07')
.replace('Aug', '08')
.replace('Sep', '09')
.replace('Oct', '10')
.replace('Nov', '11')
.replace('Dec', '12')
.replace(/\s/g, '');

// ...

const thisDateWithMonthNums = changeToMonthNums(this.state.date.toString().slice(13,15))
```

To be less repetitive, you could use an array:

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ...];
const pattern = new RegExp(months.join('|'), 'g');
const changeToMonthNums = str => str
  .replace(
    pattern,
    match => String(months.indexOf(match) + 1).padStart(2, '0')
  )
  .replace(/\s/g, '');
```

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'];
const pattern = new RegExp(months.join('|'), 'g');
const changeToMonthNums = str => str
  .replace(
    pattern,
    match => String(months.indexOf(match) + 1).padStart(2, '0')
  )
  .replace(/\s/g, '');

console.log(changeToMonthNums('foo Feb bar'));
```